# Copy folder structure with rsync glob

Tags: rsync

I'd like a command where I can do something like this:

`rsync -av a/b/**/c/* destination/`

and have it copy that entire relative path INTO destination. So for example, if there were 2 hits:

```
a/b/c/c/file.js
a/b/d/c/pic.png
```

I would want d to now looking like this:

```
destination/a/b/c/c/file.js 
destination/a/b/d/c/pic.png
```

Right now, rsync is simply placing file.js and pic.png into d, without the remaining folders.

Answer (score 3):

```
rsync -av a/  destination --include="*/" --include="b/*/c/*" --exclude="*"
```

rsync needs the --include="*/" to search through directories

Comment: It's better to add a bit more context to your answer, so future readers and readers not as experienced can follow along and learn.